# How can I write a regular expression that matchs case insensitive emails?

Tags: regex, mongoose

I have following code to find user with an email.

```
User.findOne({
        email: { $regex: new RegExp('^' + req.body.email.toLowerCase() + '$','i') }
})
```

It finds the user with a given email by lowercase letters and case insensitive search.

The problem is, we have some emails like **`john+doe@johndoe.com`** and this regular expression doesn't match those emails.

What should I add to regular expression to find that kind of emails?

Comment: Try `req.body.email.toLowerCase().replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` instead of just `req.body.email.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the e-mail address, as `req.body.email`, unescaped in a regular expression.

As you noticed, characters that have a special meaning in regexes, like `+`, will cause problems. Even worse, when a user enters `.*` as their e-mail address, your query will match *any* user, which is a security concern.

What you want is to escape the e-mail address input so any special characters will be searched for as-is (have their "special meaning" stripped from them).

The easiest way is to use a module like [`regex-escape`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex-escape) that will do that for you:

```
var escape = require('regex-escape');

...

User.findOne({
  email: { $regex: new RegExp('^' + escape(req.body.email) + '$','i') }
})
```

Since the regex is already set to match case-insensitive, there's not need to lowercase the string.

Answer (score -1):

## Description

I use this expression, it's not perfect as there are some edge cases which will slip by but those are easy enough to test by simply sending the test email:

```
^[_a-z0-9-+]+(?:\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(?:\.[a-z]{2,4})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

By adding `A-Z` to each of the character classes I've made the same expression case insensitive.

```
^[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]+(?:\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$
```

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/uC5oG4/1

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [_a-z0-9-+]+             any character of: '_', 'a' to 'z', '0' to
                           '9', '-', '+' (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [_a-z0-9-+]+             any character of: '_', 'a' to 'z', '0'
                             to '9', '-', '+' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9-]+               any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9',
                           '-' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z0-9-]+               any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to
                             '9', '-' (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]{2,4}               any character of: 'a' to 'z' (between 2
                             and 4 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The question isn't about _validating_ e-mail addresses, it's about passing addresses into a MongoDB regex query and properly escaping them. Also, validating e-mail addresses takes a much more elaborate regex than the one you're providing (TLD's can be more than 4 characters long nowadays, just to give an example). See [this page](http://rosskendall.com/blog/web/javascript-function-to-check-an-email-address-conforms-to-rfc822).

Comment: The OP asked "What should I add to regular expression to find that kind of emails", and I provided a regular expression.